# How to integrate clojurescript to existing javascript code base?

Tags: reactjs, clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I'm writing a addon feature in clojurescript using reagent. 
I would like to use this in a existing react, flux app.

How should I connect the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the ClojureScript compiler spits out JavaScript code, integration should be pretty trivial. Just add the `^:export` annotation to any ClojureScript definitions that you want to access from your JavaScript code.

```
; ClojureScript
(ns my-namespace.core)

(defn ^:export my-identity [x] x)
```

```js
// call from JavaScript
my_namespace.core.my_identity(5); // Notice how "-" is replaced with "_"
```

If you want to reference JavaScript functions/variables from your ClojureScript code, just prefix the global name with `js/`.

```
; Calling global JavaScript function from ClojureScript
(js/alert "Hello!")
```

Take a look at this [blog post on ClojureScript/JavaScript interop](http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/09/12/clojurescript-javascript-interop/) for more examples.

The JavaScript Interop section on the [ClojureScript Cheatsheet](http://cljs.info/cheatsheet/) is also a good reference. For example, it documents the `clj->js` and `js->clj` functions, which you would need to use to convert between Clojure-style objects (keywords, vectors, maps) and JavaScript-style objects (strings, arrays, maps/objects).